# Improper resize behavior of ui-grid in a modal window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

ui-grid is not resizing correctly within a modal window. Am I doing something wrong here?

http://plnkr.co/edit/gte3RmDem5dLAa33h7Kr?p=preview

```
$scope.myData = [];

$scope.gridOptions =  { 
    data: 'myData',
    rowHeight: 40,
    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
        {field:'age', displayName:'Age'},
        {field:'gender', displayName:'Gender'} ,
        {field:'ssn', displayName:'SSN'} ,
        {field:'workplace', displayName:'Workplace'} 

    ]
};

$timeout(function(){
  $scope.myData = [
    {name: "Moroni", age: 50, gender:"male", ssn:123, workplace:"foo"},
    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, gender:"female", ssn:123, workplace:"foo"},
    {name: "Jacob", age: 27, gender:"male", ssn:123, workplace:"foo"}

]; 

},0)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is more related to css than to angular.

Try to style the tables of the modal to have 100% width of the modal container, that should solve it

Comment: It only helps with the grid width but the columns are still badly resized - http://plnkr.co/edit/gte3RmDem5dLAa33h7Kr?p=preview